Help me understand the role of "friendship with Jesus" in Catholic spirituality in relation to Salve Regina
Having sang What a friend we have in Jesus since childhood, sharing with Jesus my griefs (verse 1), my struggle with temptation (verse 2), and my toiling in life (verse 3) is natural for me.  But when I encourage a lapsed Catholic friend (who grew up in pre-Vatican II era) to do the same with Jesus, I received a strong pushback, saying he is extremely uncomfortable seeing Jesus that way, how what he most appreciated about the Tridentine Mass is the utmost respect that everyone shows to God and to Christ, which is another reason he doesn't like to go to church anymore.
I happened to hear him talking to his old high school friend, who to this day remains a devoted Catholic (and who also is a catechist at his parish), telling my friend that for him missing daily mass feels like not visiting a "friend" (he meant Jesus who is present bodily in the Eucharist).  He then tried to disabuse my friend of his misconceptions of the Novus Ordo mass, how it's essentially unchanged doctrinally from the Tridentine mass, and encouraged my friend to resume his sacramental life.  I don't plan to convert my friend to Protestantism but I am trying to share the Gospel in Catholic terms.  I would be happy if my friend is willing to go to church again and to have a good relationship with Jesus, even in Catholic terms, like how his high school friend is doing.
My friend is fine praying the Rosary, which is in the same spirit as Salve Regina.  The Salve Regina text (see here, along with the history and the liturgical use of the prayer) contains similar language with What a friend we have in Jesus hymn but directed to Mary

To thee do we cry, poor banished children of Eve
To thee do we send up our sighs, mourning and weeping in this valley of tears.

followed by a request for Mary to "see" us with compassion and to "show" us Jesus:

Turn then, most gracious Advocate, thine eyes of mercy toward us.
And after this our exile show unto us the blessed fruit of thy womb, Jesus.

While I personally do not have a problem with praying to Mary as an individual believer's

spiritual mother who as the second Eve has compassion for us, casualties of the original sin of the first Eve, who like an earthly mother embraces and comforts a crying child
intercessor, praying for our salvation, along with the angels and the saints
advocate, who points us to the One who can help us: God the Father who only through Jesus Christ His Son takes away our pain, sin, and suffering by our participating in the sacraments,

I do wonder whether there is some truth in the Protestant's objection of how prayers to Mary redirect some aspects of a believer's relationship with Jesus.  It seems to me that Catholic spirituality takes a BOTH-AND approach with regards to Jesus and Mary, dividing the affections that Protestants direct solely to Jesus.  This division of affection by a Catholic seems to match the two main Catholic prayers:

relating to Mary in the Marian prayers (Rosary, Salve Regina):

as someone who understands us in our weakness like a close friend
as someone whom we are not afraid to approach, because she is "one of us"
as someone who loves us and comforts us like our earthly mother and who wants the best for us


relating to Jesus as celebrated in the Mass:

who is the awesome standard of holiness, thus reminds us of our sinfulness (Kyrie Eleison)
who is sent by the awesome glorious ruler of heaven and earth (Sanctus)
who is also the means of grace through His sacrifice (Agnus Dei, the Lamb "who takes away the sins of the world")



which then explains perfectly my friend's reticence to relate to Jesus like how the hymn suggests (as a friend).  This also explains his preferred attitude when going to mass (utmost respect).
Given the above analysis, it now makes sense to me how Eleonore Stump labels her new Atonement Theory described in his 2018 book Atonement Marian Interpretation because her theory cannot be easily subsumed under any previous theories in history, though she relies heavily on Thomas Aquinas.  In her account Jesus is portrayed as highly compassionate and as having complete solidarity with us in our weaknesses through complete mind reading in compassion & solidarity, hence the Marian aspects in Salve Regina ("see" and "show"). Believers no longer need to feel distant to God nor afraid of God's justice and holiness, but are instead motivated to lay our burdens to Jesus, receiving his love for us, being united with Him in the Eucharist, and agreeing to be molded to Jesus's image by being yoked with him.
I try to understand a theological tradition and a spirituality in their own terms, so I want to understand the Catholic logic of the devotion to both Mary and Jesus as Catholics understand it.  So, seeing how Catholics seem to relate to Mary as mother and "friend" but to Jesus mostly as Lord, Savior, and Exemplar, although both are united in love toward us (sojourners in exile, striving in the Church Militant), can you help me understand the role of "friendship with Jesus" in Catholic spirituality?

I'm not certain what exactly you mean by friendship with Jesus, but in Catholic theology, friendship with God is sanctifying grace. It is the theological virtue of charity infused into the soul by God when we are saved. I'm not sure I agree that Catholics don't relate to Jesus as friend, but only as Lord. It might be easier to answer your question if we knew what your understanding of the essence of friendship is.

@jaredad7 You read my mind.  I was about to update my question, clarifying that the Protestant concept of "friendship with Jesus" is not the same as the Catholic "friendship with God*.  The former is with the human nature of Jesus (befriending us human to human), but the latter is with the God the Father, the gulf bridged by Jesus, the enmity becomes peace through Jesus.

@jaredad7 "if we knew what your understanding of the essence of friendship is"  I'm asking the Catholic understanding of friendship in Catholic spirituality (which is why I cite Catholic prayers), not Catholic theology although the former can be informed by the latter. I already shared the Protestant meaning of "friendship with Jesus" (via the hymn text), which is analogous to human friendship. The NT language of friendship reflects this as well, which is puzzling to me how my Catholic friend is so uncomfortable with making friends with Jesus (maybe because he's not Biblically literate).

Yeah, so I think a lot of people in the West today think of friendship only in terms of friendships of pleasure. My friend is a guy I go get a beer with after work and maybe play darts with or he stands in my wedding and we're on the same community baseball team. Stuff like that. So when you say to someone "Jesus is my friend," if they have that kind of understanding of friendship, they are going to be confused. I think both Catholics and Protestants conceive of friendship with Jesus as something distinctly different from this.

To the point about becoming friends with the human nature of Jesus, I would reject this notion entirely. Jesus is one Divine Person with two natures. We don't make friends with natures, in a Catholic understanding, but with persons. Friendship with Christ is friendship with a Divine Person.

I meant being friends with Jesus the created human being (body & soul) of God, rather than being friends with the transcendent God who only partially revealed Himself. Yes, Jesus IS a Divine Person, but we can understand his humanity more completely than his divinity, thus including his action as this Divine Person operating in his human nature. Eleonore Stump's explanation helps me a lot to think correctly about the dual nature of Jesus. Anyway I'd like to learn Catholics' interpretation of friendship verses in the Bible, applied to spirituality.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
